# Space complexity when temporary variables declared within loop

Tags: python, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I'm trying to assess the space complexity of a LeetCode solution. I believe it boils down to the following simplification:

```py
def algorithm(string):
    for _ in range(10):
        temporary_string = copy.copy(string)
    return None
```

Would this algorithm's space complexity be `O(1)` or `O(len(string))`?

---

The full algorithm is:

```py
    def validWordAbbreviation(self, word: str, abbr: str) -> bool:
        a, b = 0, 0
        
        while a < len(word) and b < len(abbr):
            nextB = b + 1
            while abbr[b].isdigit() and nextB < len(abbr) and abbr[nextB].isdigit():
                nextB += 1
            
            bWord = abbr[b:nextB]
            if bWord.isdigit():
                if bWord != bWord.lstrip('0'):
                    return False
                a += int(bWord)
            else:
                if word[a] != bWord:
                    return False
                a += 1
            
            b = nextB
        
        return a == len(word) and b == len(abbr)
```

This is a solution to the LeetCode problem 408. Valid Word Abbreviation posted in the discussion forum. [Source](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-word-abbreviation/discuss/1507555/Python-Straight-Forward-O(n)-Runtime-O(1)-Space-Solution-(Beats-100)).

The author claims it is `O(1)` space complexity but a comment disagrees and claims it is `O(len(abbr))` due to the declaration of the `bWord` variable.

Which is correct?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `copy.copy()` on a string shouldn't do much at all. `abbr[b:nextB]` will allocate new memory for the sliced string.

Comment: I think both approaches would allocate new memory for the string? As `abbr[b:nextB]` does at least, would you say that algorithm's space complexity scales with the length of `abbr`?